# How do I edit onscreen text in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a display for Lives which says "Lives:0." When you press any key, lives will go down by 1, and I have called it as print `self.lives -= 1` so that the console is confirming that lives are `-=1`, but the display stays the same. I want Lives to do gown on screen.

```
self.lives = 5

sysfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
self.text = sysfont.render("Lives: %d" % self.lives, True, (255, 255, 255))

While running:

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    
  print "Ouch"
  self.lives -= 1
  print self.lives

rect = self.text.get_rect()
    rect = rect.move(500,500)
    self.screen.blit(self.text, rect)
```

Comment: You have not shown your code for actually showing the display.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-render the text every time `lives` changes. Here's a quick demo:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 200, False, False)

    lives = 5

    while True:
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            lives -= 1

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        text = font.render(str(lives), True, (0,0,0))

        screen.blit(text, (25, 25))
        pygame.display.flip()

main()
```

To make it more efficient, you could try re-rendering only when the key is pressed, instead of once every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need to do is add:
 `self.text = sysfont.render("Lives: %d" % self.lives, True, (255, 255, 255))`
 to your `if` as seen below:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    
  print "Ouch"
  self.lives -= 1
  print self.lives
  self.text = sysfont.render("Lives: %d" % self.lives, True, (255, 255, 255))
```

If you only have this line at the beginning, then you're always going to print what `self.lives` originally was.  You need to update it, but you only need to do so when the event is triggered.